# click a menu option using selenium

Tags: java, javascript, html, selenium

I have  a menu dropdown like this.
  Using selenium i need to move the mouse to menu item Documentation and click the option App Configuration from that.
  mouse hover is working fine.But am not able to click the option element app Configuration.

```
    <li class="current">
    <a href="/docs">Documentation</a>
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <li>
            <a href="/docs">API Reference</a>
        </li>

        <li><a href="/docs/api/oauth2">OAuth 2.0 Guide</a></li>


        <li class="current"><a href="/docs/configuration">App Configuration</a></li>
        <li><a href="/docs/guidelines">Tech Guidelines</a></li>
        <li><a href="/docs/best-practices">Best Practices</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="">
    <a href="/tools">Tools</a>
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <li><a href="/tools/quickstart">Quick Start</a></li>
        <li><a href="/tools/testing">Testing</a></li>
        <li><a href="/tools/devbox">Developer STB</a></li>
        <li><a href="/tools/reference">Reference Apps</a></li>


    </ul>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="/updates">Updates</a>
</li>
```

When i mouse over any of the menu links like Documentation or Tools  the    `<li class=""> becomes  <li class="open">`

While i tried using below code mouse hover to Documentation link is happend!!
And the mouse pointer moved to the 'App Configuration' option .But click event is not happening.How it can possible

```
Actions action = new Actions(webdriver);
WebElement we = webdriver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href = '/docs'"));
action.moveToElement(we).build.perform();

WebElement config = webdriver.findElement(By.xpath("(//a[contains(@href,'/docs/configuration')])[1]));
action.moveToElement(config).click().build.perform();
```

i need to click the app configuration option

Comment: Please post what errors are you getting while trying the above codes. Also, could you post the url of the site page in question?

Comment: am gettiing errors while verifying the elements in the app configuration page.it will be opened by clicking the app configuration option from the documentation menu.so that step will fail.but clcking is not happening  and not redirected to configuration page

Comment: Could you post the site url?

Comment: site url need to login first to validate these elements.

Answer (score 0):

No need to pass index in xpath, in html href is unique. so you can directly give xpath. like:

```
   WebElement config = webdriver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href,'/docs/configuration')]"));
```

Comment: No in my webpage it contains multiple'/docs/configuration href's thats y i used.

Comment: if that index is not presnt then how mouse pointer will move to that element.that is happening now

Comment: can you post your website..?

Comment: Try to use this xpath: " By.xpath("//li[@class='current']/a[text()='App Configuration']") .

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//li[@class='open']/a[text()='App Configuration']"}

Comment: Please use this xpath: By.xpath("//nav[@id='topnav']/div/div/ul/li[2]/ul/li[3]/a");. Its working.

Comment: is it like `WebElement config = webdriver.findElement(By.xpath("By.xpath("//nav[@id='topnav']/div/div/ul/li[2]/ul/li[3]/a")));
action.moveToElement(config).click().build.perform();`

Comment: no need to perform mouse over. In your case its working na. That xpath is only for clicking purpose. webdriver.findElement(By.xpath("//nav[@id='topnav']/div/div/ul/li[2]/u‌​l/li[3]/a")).click(); This will perform click action on APp Configuration.

Comment: But it is not working.app config options is seems as selected but clik is not happening..i dont know...

Answer (score 0):

Call directly click on the WebElement (no need for `Actions`):

```
By loc = By.xpath("(//a[contains(@href,'/docs/configuration')])[1]");
WebElement config = webdriver.findElement(loc);
config.click();
```

Works for me with selenium-java-2.44.0 (although '/docs/configuration' is not a valid target in my setup).